# Conditionally updating the columns PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have embedded the MySQL statements in PHP code. Following is my code:

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE labdata1 SET Date='$d1' WHERE SL=1";
```

I want to set the column "Date" to null after 48 hours. What I tried is this:

```
UPDATE labdata1 
    SET Date=NULL 
    WHEN Update_time <(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)
```

but there is a bug in MySQL database that keeps `Update_time` system column in MySQL always `NULL`

Therefore rather than writing a procedure in MySQL database, I want to do it through PHP code.

Kindly let me know how can do it through PHP code?

Comment: so you have update_time column in labdata1 ? far as i know there is no updated_time in information_schema.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set that particular rows where update time that past 48 hours you can it like this:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$sql = 'UPDATE labdata1 
    SET Date = NULL 
    WHERE Update_time >= DATE_ADD(Update_time,  INTERVAL -2 DAY)';
$query = $db->query($sql);
if($query->affected_rows > 0) {
    // update successful!
}
```

Comment: Does this works even if UPDATE_TIME column is always null and it never updates?

Comment: I found the solution. I had to create custom column which shows the updated time of a particular row. ALTER TABLE 'labdata1' ADD updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Sorry I'm novice to database. I have one more question. Is it possible to make this query run every time I update something in the table.